# Dialogflow - Fulfillment Inline Editor(Firebase) is timeout

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

I am testing with Dialogflow using Firebase project.

The Firebase Project is already used as an android backend. (Firestore)

Now, I am trying to attach chatbot.

[This github code is what I want.](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-firestore-nodejs)

1. I create a new Dialogflow Agent, it refers to the Firebase project.
2. Enable Fullfillment Inline Editor, and I copy&paste a code from upper github code.

```js
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:*'; // enables lib debugging statements
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

  function writeToDb (agent) {
    const databaseEntry = agent.parameters.databaseEntry;
    const dialogflowAgentRef = db.collection('dialogflow').doc('agent');
    return db.runTransaction(t => {
      t.set(dialogflowAgentRef, {entry: databaseEntry});
      return Promise.resolve('Write complete');
    }).then(doc => {
      agent.add(`Wrote "${databaseEntry}" to the Firestore database.`);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(`Error writing to Firestore: ${err}`);
      agent.add(`Failed to write "${databaseEntry}" to the Firestore database.`);
    });
  }

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('WriteToFirestore', writeToDb);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);   // Here is index.js:51
});
```

This is very simple.

It just writes a text into the Firestore.
That's all.

I deployed this fulfillment and linked to an Intent.

In case of first conversation after deploy, I can find below log in Firebase Cloud Functions.

```
Error: No handler for requested intent
at WebhookClient.handleRequest (/user_code/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:317:29)
at exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment.functions.https.onRequest (/user_code/index.js:51:9)
at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:57:9)
```

And after some times, when I retry again, I can find below logs in the Firebase Cloud Functions.

```
dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment - Function execution took 60002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'
```

I don't know what I am missing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was my fault.

The key of intentMap should be same with Intent name.
After I fix it, it works fine.